# How to asynchronously databind a user control after web service request finishes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page (let's call it DocumentPage) that displays multiple lists of files, each of which use the same user control (DocumentList).  DocumentList is given a root folder, and then invokes a web service (DocumentManager) to retrieve the file list using said root folder in order to render itself.

This slows down the initial load time significantly.  I've wrapped each instance of DocumentList in an UpdatePanel, and would like change them to only data bind and render once the file retrieval is complete.

A few mockups of what this looks like:

**DocumentList.ascx.cs:**

```
public class DocumentList {
    public string Root { get; set; }
    private IEnumerable<string> documents;
    protected IEnumerable<string> Documents => documents ?? documents = RetrieveDocuments(Root);

    private IEnumerable<string> RetrieveDocuments(string root) 
    {
        return DocumentManager.ListFiles(root);
    }

    public override void DataBind()
    {
        if (this.Enabled) base.DataBind();
    }

    protected string ToUrl(string s) { ... }

}
```

**DocumentList.ascx:**

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Files" runat="server" DataSource="<%# Documents %> "ItemType="System.String">
        <a href="<%# ToUrl(Item) %>" ><%# Item %> </a>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

A few things I've tried:

-Wrap the calls to DocumentList.DataBind in a Task during Page_Load, with the hopes of delaying execution until everything else finishes loading.  Unfortunately works too well, since it isn't run until the session is disposed.

-Change DocumentList.DataBind like so:

```
public override void DataBind()
{
    if (this.Enabled) 
    {
        var t = new Task(() => documents = RetrieveDocuments(Root));
        await t.ContinueWith(e => base.DataBind());
    }
}
```

In the Tasks tab on Visual Studio, the task just hangs there "Awaiting" and never actually executes.  I put the UpdatePanel on a postback timer and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the [async attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45#CreatingAsynchGizmos) in the page and then do:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(DataBindRepeater));
}

private async Task DataBindRepeater()
{
    documents = await RetrieveDocuments(Root);
    /*More code*/
}
```

You have to keep in mind a few things:
 * The async attribute is at page level, not user control level.
 * The tasks registered using [RegisterAsyncTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask?view=netframework-4.7.2) are executed late in the flow, even afterthe PreRender event.

Comment: I did this:
```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(DataBindRepeater));
}

private async Task DataBindRepeater()
{
    documents = await new Task<IEnumerable<string>>(() => RetrieveDocuments(Root));
    base.DataBind();
}
```

It's now just hanging when I try to load the page.

Comment: You need to code RetrieveDocuments in a way it can be async. Wrapping it into a Task won't work